# Don't kill queue worker on job timeout

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs

Is there a way to tell Laravel to not kill the queue when a job times-out?

I want to set `$timeout` on a particular job class, but I don't want the queue to stop if one of these jobs times-out.

Does Laravel provide a way to achieve this?

Or perhaps I should be using something other than `$timeout` to make my job class stop after a pre-defined number of seconds(?)